# Pagination not working in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use pagination in Laravel 4 with quite a complex query (using Fluent query builder I think).

**Query SQL Code**

```
SELECT `description`, `email`, `website`, `telephone`, `purpose`, `services`,      
       `eligibilitycriteria`, `meetingplace`, `servicecosts`, `area`, 
       `servicetype`, `beneficiarytype`, `charitynumber`, `address`, `contacts`, 
MATCH (
       `name`,`description`,`email`,`website`,`telephone`,`purpose`,`services`,
       `eligibilitycriteria`,`meetingplace`,`servicecosts`,`area`,`servicetype`,
       `beneficiarytype`,`charitynumber`,`address`,`contacts`
      ) 
AGAINST ("dan") AS Score0, 
MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ("dan") AS Score1 FROM `directory_cache`   
WHERE MATCH(
       `description`,`email`,`website`,`telephone`,`purpose`,`services`,
       `eligibilitycriteria`,`meetingplace`,`servicecosts`,`area`,`servicetype`,
       `beneficiarytype`,`charitynumber`,`address`,`contacts`
      ) 
AGAINST ("dan") 
ORDER BY (Score0*1 + Score1*1.5) DESC
```

I am calling the paginate at the end of the query builder in my controller like follows:

```
$results = $query->paginate(20);
```

Then in my view I simply call `$results->links` and I do get the pagination buttons for next page and the numbered pages etc.

But when I click on Page 2, this is where I encounter the problem.

My form uses POST to submit the search form. Both the get and post actions use the same view file to display the search form and results.

Please help and if you need any more information I am happy to edit the post and add it in, I am here all night!

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to route both `viewResults` and `search` to the same route using `Route::any()` so that you would need to perform seperate functionality for both actions

**routes.php**

`Route::any('/list','Controller@viewResults');`

**Controller.php**

```
function viewResults(){

    $searchQuery = Input::get('searchQuery');
    if(isset($searchQuery))
       $query = DirectoryCache::where(...)->where(...);
    else
       $query = DirectoryCache::where(1, '=', 1);

    $results = $query->paginate();

    //This will append the searchQuery to your pagination links
    $results->appends(array('searchQuery'=>$searchQuery));
}
```

So irrespective of you perform a `POST` or `GET` you would execute the same action and still be able to perform search and get the results. I hope this helps

Comment: This answer should be chosen as featured!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use GET or store the query in session, I don't see an easier way of doing this.
Using POST like you do is bad practice anyway. You shoud POST and then redirect from there, either passing GET parameters or keeping the query in session.

```
function post_search() {
    $query = DirectoryCache::where(...)->where(...);
    Session::put('searchQuery', $query);

    return Redirect::to_action('controller@viewResults');
}

function get_viewResults($page = 1) {
    $perPage = 20;

    $query = Session::get('searchQuery', DirectoryCache::where(1, '=', 1));
    $query = $query->paginate();
    $query->skip($page * $perPage)->take($perPage);

    $results = $query->get(); 
    ...
}
```

I know it's Laravel 3, I haven't touched 4 yet, but the APIs should be almost the same.

Comment: Where you wrote `return Redirect::to_action('controller@viewResults');` did you mean controller@get_viewResults?
Also, how would I use GET as you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: I'm not using GET. I'm passing data aroun using the session. With GET you would need to pass around a lot of parameters so it probably is impractical in your case. Sorry about the `get_` confusion, that's the syntax for RESTful controllers, you can read about it here http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers . Keep in mind there are some differences in naming conventions from 3 to 4.